# .Net Core cursor within a cursor

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, cursor

I'm busy working on a .Net Core Web Application and I was wondering if it is possible to execute a cursor within another cursor.

I have the following code which I thought would work

```
string string = null;
SqlCommand collections_cur = null;
SqlCommand headings_cur = null;
int cl_idno = 0;

sqlserv.Open();

string = " select * from collections " +
         " where cl_idno >= @cl_idno ";
collections_cur = new SqlCommand(string, sqlserv);

string = " select * from headings " +
         " where hd_cl_idno = @hd_cl_idno ";
headings_cur = new SqlCommand(string, sqlserv);

collections_cur.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameters("cl_idno", 1));
using(SqlDataReader reader1 = collections_cur.ExecuteReader())
{

    while(reader1.Read())
    {

        // some stuff

        cl_idno = reader1.GetInt32(0);

        headings_cur.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameters("hd_cl_idno", cl_idno));
        using(SqlDataReader reader2 = headings_cur.ExecuteReader())
        {

            while(reader2.Read())
            {

                // more stuff

            }

        }

    }

}

sqlserv.Close();
```

The above is crashing though with the following error

```
InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
```

I thought that it would treat reader1 and reader2 separately but I'm not sure how to use a second DataReader object correctly.

*PS*

I know that I could do this with a single cursor using

```
select * from collections
left join headings on hd_cl_idno = cl_idno
where cl_idno >= 1
```

But I am using this simplified code so that the question is easy to read. There are instances where I need a cursor within a cursor and this code is just to illustrate the problem

Comment: Some things are best done in memory.....

Comment: Don't reuse the same SqlConnection object. This is what is causing the problem, just create a new SqlConnection for each command.

Comment: @GarethD comment will fix your exception, but you're opening yourself to a world of pain with this approach.

Comment: I find it very surprising that using cursors within cursors is taboo in C#. Cursors within cursor feels so natural in TSQL, Genero and many other languages I've worked with

Comment: If Cursors within Cursors in TSQL feel natural to you then I dread to see what your queries look like. A cursor should be a last resort in T-SQL (or any branch of SQL for that matter), and I don't think there are any situations that would ever call for a cursor within a cursor, it would pain me deeply if I ever had to do this. It is far from natural!

Comment: It's for simplicity and readability. A main cursor would fetch necessary data and a specific row may need a sub-cursor to do additional checks or execute additional logic on different tables. I prefer it personally over one mammoth sql statement that would join in unnecessary tables if it's only needed for 20% of the results. Like I said it's my personal choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is frowned upon by C# developers but I have a solution anyway if it might benefit anyone. You should probably use it at your own risk or not use it all but it works for me.

I have made the following adjustments to the code

```
//
// define and initialize variables
//

string credentials = null;
SqlConnection sqlserv = null;
string lv_string = null;
SqlCommand collections_cur = null;
SqlCommand headings_cur = null;
int cl_idno = 0;

//
// connect to database
// MultipleActiveResultSets=True was added
// to allow usage of multiple cursors
//

credentials = "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;" +
              "Initial Catalog=rescratch;" +
              "Integrated Security=True;" +
              "Connect Timeout=30;" +
              "Encrypt=False;" +
              "TrustServerCertificate=True;" +
              "ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;" +
              "MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" +
              "MultiSubnetFailover=False";

sqlserv = new SqlConnection(credentials);

sqlserv.Open();

//
// declare cursors
//

lv_string = " select * from collections " +
            " where cl_idno >= @cl_idno ";
collections_cur = new SqlCommand(lv_string, gv_sqlserv);
collections_cur.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameters("cl_idno", 0));

lv_string = " select * from headings " +
            " where hd_cl_idno = @hd_cl_idno ";
headings_cur = new SqlCommand(lv_string, gv_sqlserv);
headings_cur.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameters("hd_cl_idno", 0));

//
// main cursor
//

// set parameter
collections_cur.Parameters["cl_idno"].Value = 1;
using(SqlDataReader lv_reader1 = collections_cur.ExecuteReader())
{

    while(lv_reader1.Read())
    {

        // some stuff

        cl_idno = lv_reader1.GetInt32(0);

        //
        // sub cursor
        //

        // set parameter
        headings_cur.Parameters["hd_cl_idno"].Value = cl_idno;
        using(SqlDataReader lv_reader2 = headings_cur.ExecuteReader())
        {

            while(lv_reader2.Read())
            {

                // more stuff

            }

        }

    }

}

sqlserv.Close();
```